# How to add files to a .bundle file in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode5, assets

I am working on an iOS application that I did not create and I would like to add some audio and image assets to the project. Right now these are all located in a `.bundle` file and accessed like this:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle.bundle/some_audio" ofType:@"m4a"]`

My question is, how do I add new assets to `MyBundle.bundle`? I have located `MyBundle.bundle` in the project navigator and on the filesystem but I can't figure out how to add files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. Locate the `.bundle` in Finder (in XCode you can right click and select "Show in Finder")
2. Right click the `.bundle` and choose "Show Package Contents"
3. Drag files into the new finder window that opens

Comment: How do I add the file while I build the project using Xcode? I don't want to manually drag and drop it. Sorry I know am almost 7yrs late.

Comment: @AnanthKamath, have you figured it out?

Comment: @David, hey i don't remember now which approach i used to solved this issue. It was a pet project. Sorry.